# SSIS HH::MM:SS to seconds with the HH part being more than 24 in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I am trying to have an SSIS derived column that will transform HH:MM:SS from a flat file to just seconds in the database.

The issue I am having and not seeming to find out how to online is when the HH is over 24.

For instance one of the csv file has 178:29:00.

I was using `(DT_NUMERIC,10,2)(((DT_I4)SUBSTRING([SPEED OF ANSWER],1,2) * 3600) + ((DT_I4)SUBSTRING([SPEED OF ANSWER],4,2) * 60) + ((DT_NUMERIC,4,2)RIGHT([SPEED OF ANSWER],2)))` when the hours was under 24.

But that does not work if it is over 24.

Comment: *If* I recall correct, Excel doesn't actually have a "time" field, just date and time. Values that are time but are a value on are after `24:00:00` are actually just dates after `1900-01-00`. So `01:00` is `1900-01-00 00:01:00` but `25:00` and `178:29` are `1900-01-01 01:00` and `1900-01-07 10:29` respectively. You might, therefore, be better off importing the value as a date first.

Comment: Oh, it's it's a CSV file, import it as text then. Then you can just split the hours/minutes/seconds into sections and it's simple maths.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding the question.

Comment: @SBA `178:29:00` is a duration, not time. SQL Server  don't have a duration type. The `time` type is meant to hold the time of day and can't accept values above 24:00. You'll have to import this type as something else, but first you'll have to decide how to store it. You can't use `time` or `datetime2`. In C# you can use `TimeSpan` but there's no equivalent in SQL Server

Comment: If you really want to just save seconds, you can add a Script transform that parses the text to a TimeSpan then returns `TimeSpan.TotalSeconds`. This avoids the error prone string manipulation and can easily handle values less than 1 hour

Comment: You can use [TOKEN(character_expression, delimiter_string, occurrence)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/token-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15) in an SSIS expression instead of manually splitting to get individual parts too, eg `(DT_I4)TOKEN([SPEED OF ANSWER],':',1)*3600 + ...`. You'd have to use TOKENCOUNT to get the actual number of parts in case hours are ommitted

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos please write your token piece as an answer so I can give you credit for answering my question.

Answer (score 1):

here is a script component.

```
string time = row.YourTimeRowAsString;

var t = time.Split(':');

int secs = 0;
switch(t.length)
{
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        secs = int.Parse(t[0]);
        break;
    case 2:
        secs = 60* int.Parse(t[0]) + int.Parse(t[1]);
        break;
    case 3:
        secs = 60*60*int.Parse(t[0]) + 60*int.Parse(t[1]) + int.Parse(t[2]);
        break;
}
```

Comment: You can use `TimeSpan.Parse` to parse the string directly. There's no need to split in C#

Comment: glad i answered this question only to learn a new and better solution. #always learning.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it is to split the varchar into different values, and then just sum them.
What you did wrong in your code is that you did not take the number of digits for the hour part in account.
Here is an example on how you could do that, the example is in SQL because I don't know much of ssis.
Hopefully it can help you

```
declare @s varchar(20) = '178:29:00'

select convert(int, left(@s, charindex(':', @s) - 1)) * 3600 +
       convert(int, substring(@s, charindex(':', @s) + 1, 2)) * 60 +
       convert(int, right(@s, 2))
```

This is without checking if there are invalid values, you still have to do that.
I also assume that the `minute` and the `second` part are always 2 digits long

Comment: This won't work if the duration is less than 1 hour

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `declare @s varchar(20) = '00:29:00'` will return 1740, so why would it not work ? Can you explain more please

Comment: You assume `00:` will be available. The code you posted is the equivalent in SQL of what the OP had already posted

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes I assume there will at least be one `0` present for hours. The difference with my code and the code from the OP is that his code only works when  exact 2 digits are present, mine works when at lease one digit is present

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So my code also works with more then 2 digits for hours

Comment: Your code is SQL, not a derived column expression. It can't even run in SSIS, which suggests the OP didn't use that answer but translated it back to an SSIS expression.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos There I agree, my code cannot be used like that in ssis, but it seems he used the idea to count the number of digits for the hours part, which he did not do in his code. So it does seems my answer put him in the correct direction. I don't know ssis so I answered in sql, which got him on the right track. Is that so bad ?

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect that